# Subfolder install not working

Tags: htaccess, server, apache

I have my main site inside the root `public_html` folder, and that is working fine. Alongside that I have 2 subfolder installations, out of which only one is working.

I made no changes to my `.htaccess` folder, except that I set up basic auth on the second subfolder as I don't want this to be public.

But for some reason, when I go to `mysite.com/subsite2` I keep getting 404.

I tried adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subsite2/(.*)$ [NC]
```

inside my `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block on the main site, which worked, but then none of my subpages on the original site worked. Which is not good.

For the first subfolder I set up years ago, I didn't have to make any changes, and it just worked ‍♂️.

My main `.htaccess` looks like this (has modifications from WP Rocket and Wordfence)

```
# BEGIN WP Rocket v3.12.6.1
# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddCharset UTF-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml
</IfModule>

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

# Since we’re sending far-future expires, we don’t need ETags for static content.
# developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Powered-By "WP Rocket/3.12.6.1"
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType image/avif                                  avif
    AddType image/avif-sequence                         avifs
</IfModule>
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                              "access plus 1 month"
    # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest           "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Your document html
    ExpiresByType text/html                     "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Data
    ExpiresByType text/xml                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    # Feed
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml           "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml          "access plus 1 hour"
    # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                  "access plus 1 week"
    # Media: images, video, audio
    ExpiresByType image/gif                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/png                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/avif                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/avif-sequence           "access plus 4 months"
    # HTC files  (css3pie)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component              "access plus 1 month"
    # Webfonts
    ExpiresByType font/ttf                      "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/otf                      "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                     "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2                    "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                 "access plus 4 months"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    # CSS and JavaScript
    ExpiresByType text/css                      "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript        "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# Gzip compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Active compression
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Force deflate for mangled headers
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
# Don’t compress images and other uncompressible content
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|rar|zip|exe|flv|mov|wma|mp3|avi|swf|mp?g|mp4|webm|webp|pdf)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# END WP Rocket

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/user/public_html/example.com/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
php_value auto_prepend_file '/home/user/public_html/example.com/wordfence-waf.php'
</IfModule>
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

What am I missing here?

The `.htaccess` from the protected subsite looks like this:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd
# Section managed by cPanel: Password Protected Directories     -cp:ppd
# - Do not edit this section of the htaccess file!              -cp:ppd
#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "customusername"
AuthUserFile "/home/user/.htpasswds/public_html/example.com/subsite2/passwd"
Require valid-user
#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd
# End section managed by cPanel: Password Protected Directories -cp:ppd
#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd

# BEGIN WordPress
# Direktive (redci) između "BEGIN WordPress" i "END WordPress" su
# dinamički generirani, i trebalo bi ih mijenjati samo koristeći WordPressove filtre.
# Sve promjene direktiva između navedenih markera bit će prepisane.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /subsite2/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subsite2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I changed the URLs in the files for privacy sake.

Comment: Presumably SITE_URL and HOME_URL are set appropriately in the admin section?

Comment: Yes, in both the main site and all the subsites

Comment: WordPress would not 404 a path that actually exists, so have you tried flushing the rewrite rules in the subsite2 (just visit the permalink settings admin page)? Have you tried deactivating plugins on subsite2? If yes to both that and none helped, then maybe doing that on the main site might help? But are you getting 404 error pages from WordPress, or are they standard 404 pages from the server? Is this happening only when you visit `/subsite2` (no sub-path), or also `/subsite2/<anything>` ?

Comment: Tried flushing permalink settings on all sites. I will try to disable both rocket cache and wordence which seem to be modifying the htaccess, but it's super odd that one of the subpage is working, and the other not. The 404 page is the WordPress one.
Every subpage on the subsite is throwing 404

Comment: Then perhaps removing the basic auth from the htaccess file would help... but what is the actual name of `subsite2` and the other subsite? And BTW, please tag me when replying so that I get notified of your replies.

Comment: This line `RewriteBase /subsite2/` along with `RewriteRule . /subsite2/index.php [L]` doesn't make sense. Id say remove your rewrite rule in that sub-install (you can leave auth parameters). The main site `.htaccess` should already handle the rewrite rule in your sub-install